# is SICP still recommended?

Tags: scheme, sicp

I have some experience with python, I asked for a new language, and said that i am having a hard time implementing what I have learned. they suggested I learn SICP. Saying it uses a great language and teaches great programming fundamentals.

But I notice it was published in 1984. Do you guys recommend it, or have I been trolled? :p

Thanks.

Comment: What are your goals? Are you wanting to understand better how programming languages work? Or are you wanting to just make something useful in the short term? Or are you looking for a job? SICP is still recommendable, but it very much depends what you want to get from it.

Comment: the first one really, also, maybe to find the right language for me.

Comment: Then go for it. But Scheme won't really be the long-term language for you, but it will help you understand what you should look for in a language.

Comment: @Eric: "Won't" is a strong word. There are some of us here who do still prefer Scheme to any other language, because it's just that awesome. :-)

Comment: A couple of years ago, I used SICP as a way to learn clojure.  I documented some of my experience here: http://loufranco.com/blog/files/category-20-days-of-clojure.html (start from the bottom) -- also I linked to the SICP lectures.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, SICP is still a great book! The second edition, which is [available online](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), as of 1996. Although, if you just want to learn Scheme instead of fundamental computer science, you might be better off with [*Teach Yourself Scheme in Fixnum Days*](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/t-y-scheme/t-y-scheme.html).

Answer (score 14):

I strongly encourage you to check out the book [How to Design Programs](http://htdp.org).  It focuses on the fundamentals of programming, not on the specific language, but it also uses Scheme as its language.  It's also available [free online](http://htdp.org).

You can also check out the current release of the [second edition](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/), which is in preparation (or the less-stable but more up-to-date [current draft](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/Draft/)).

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, you're loooking at the first edition. The second edition is from 1996.

You should VERY MUCH tackle the book. I've gone through about half and my mind is blown. I can't begin to explain how amazing it is. Not only will you develop an appreciation for elegance in programming, but you'll see the line blurred between coding and computer science.

Don't approach this book like a programming book. Approach it as if you want to learn the fundamentals of computation and computer science using programming as a means of expression.

Answer (score 12):

SICP is one of the best books I've read for learning how to write programs well.  I never used scheme outside of the work I did in that book, but it's well worth your time.